# Get browser and command line access with Digest Based Authentication proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, authentication

Sometimes I need to download files (and do other things) via command line; I have always declared the environment variable `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` or `ftp_proxy` in that way too. For example:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@address:port/
```

Some days ago, the network administrators started to use [Digest Based Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2384230/2943403) in the proxy (for security reasons), and now I can access Internet through the browser, but not from the command line.

How can I get access through the browser and command line?